# How do I write a function signature such that it will take in a container or a range?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

I was trying to make a *single* function that takes in a container and implicitly have it convert to a `boost::iterator_range` as I thought that was it's purpose, but it seems that I'm missing something.

Here's an example of what I was thinking:

```cpp
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <vector>

template<typename IT>
void fn_x(boost::iterator_range<IT>) {
}

void fn_y() {
    std::vector<int> a(64);
    fn_x(boost::make_iterator_range(a.begin(), a.end())); // Works
    fn_x(a);                                              // Doesn't
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/3T6MM3141)

So how would I get `fn_x` to accept both a container and a range object, in the same function?

Sorry, forgot to mention that I'm using c++14.

Comment: With [one level of indirection](https://godbolt.org/z/3xzrroorv)?

Comment: Does it [have to be](https://godbolt.org/z/dPMoa39j1) explicitly `boost::iterator_range`?

Comment: @Caleth, no it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "obvious" answer is to be less specific: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d98fb896c422ddc4)**

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

template <typename Range> auto fn_x(Range&& r) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return accumulate(begin(r), end(r), 0.0);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a{1,2,3};

    std::cout << fn_x(boost::make_iterator_range(a.begin(), a.end())) << "\n";
    std::cout << fn_x(a) << "\n";
}
```

Prints 6 two times.

If you really want to be more specific consider:

- `std::span` (c++20) - which has implicit conversions from e.g. `std::vector`
- range concepts (c++20)
- if all else fails, [sfinae](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

```
template <typename It> auto fn_x(boost::iterator_range<It> r) {
    return accumulate(r.begin(), r.end(), 0.0);
}

template <typename SomeOtherRange,
          typename Enable =
              decltype(boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(std::declval<SomeOtherRange>()),
                                                  std::end(std::declval<SomeOtherRange>())))>
auto fn_x(SomeOtherRange const& r) {
    return fn_x(boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(r), std::end(r)));
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38c34799f10c56f8)** (c++11 compatible)

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

template <typename It> double fn_x(boost::iterator_range<It> r) {
    return accumulate(r.begin(), r.end(), 0.0);
}

template <typename SomeOtherRange,
          typename Enable =
              decltype(boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(std::declval<SomeOtherRange>()),
                                                  std::end(std::declval<SomeOtherRange>())))>
double fn_x(SomeOtherRange const& r) {
    return fn_x(boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(r), std::end(r)));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3};

    std::cout << fn_x(boost::make_iterator_range(a.begin(), a.end())) << "\n";
    std::cout << fn_x(a) << "\n";
}
```

Still printing

```
6
6
```

Comment: Cheers @Adrian for the edit. I missed it when previewing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iterator>

template<typename IT>
void fn_x(boost::iterator_range<IT>) {
}

template<typename Range>
void fn_x(Range r) {
   fn_x(boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(r), std::end(r));
}
```

I'm assuming that `Range` will come with a `begin` and `end` method

Comment: So you're saying that I need a separate function overload to do this.  I was assuming that `boost::iterator_range` had a conversion function already.  Why is that not the case?

Comment: @Adrian because `boost::iterator_range` exists to adapt pairs of iterators into a range, a container is already a range.

Comment: Lol, I just realized that you almost had it right.  You don't need the overload though.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

If you have access to c++20 you could try `std::span`.

Look at this monstrosity:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <span>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct ExistsFunctor {
  using UnderlyingT = typename T::value_type;
  bool operator()(std::span<UnderlyingT> span, UnderlyingT needle) {
    return std::find(span.begin(), span.end(), needle) != span.end();
  }
};

template <typename Container, typename T>
bool Exist(Container &container, T needle) {
  auto functor = ExistsFunctor<Container>();
  return functor(container, needle);
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> arr{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

  bool ok = Exist(arr, 3);

  if (ok) {
    std::cout << "ok" << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cout << "not ok" << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what does this have to do with my original question?

Comment: Did not know it was boost specific at the time of the answer...